# FlowPlayer: Is there an equivalent for the html5 "timeupdate" event, so I can get the currentTime property of flowPlayer Object?

Tags: html, flowplayer

```js
$("video").on('timeupdate', function() {
    console.log(this.currentTime); 
});
```

Like this, How do I console the flowPlayer object currentTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do

```
flowplayer(function (api, root) {
   api.on("progress", function (e, api) {
      console.log(api.video.time);
   });
});
```